# WebGL - Looping through an array in a shader

Tags: javascript, webgl

I wondering how I am supposed to loop through an array from a shader.
I've read a lot of things but I'm still quite confused.

Here is the JavaScript that creates the array:

```
var particles = []; // I'm creating an array of x and y coordinates
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    particles.push([
            Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) + .5, 
            Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) + .5
        ]);
}
gl.uniform2fv(gl.getUniformLocation(glProgram, 'particles'), particles);
```

And here is a piece of my fragment shader:

```
uniform vec2 particles;

void main( void ) {
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
        if (particles[i].x == 1.0) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is "**field selection requires structure or vector on left hand side**". 
What am I missing?

Comment: Don't know much about WebGL, but I would guess your declaration of `particles` in your shader is incorrect, it should probably be `uniform vec2 particles[100];`.

Comment: Well you're right. You just saved me a lot of time, thanks!

Comment: FYI: Of course do whatever you want but it's not common to use large arrays of uniforms given that the min max size is 128. Meaning if you declare `uniform vec2 particles[129]` where will be many GPUs that can't run the shader because they support a maximum array size of 128. (currently [1 of 4 will fail](https://webglstats.com/webgl/parameter/MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS)) Typically if you need random access to data you put that data in a texture.

Comment: Passing by this question, but without additional context your code gives me the sense that you might want to re-organize your data so you know which points have a `.x` of 1.0 before the shader steps. You could create separate buffers. That way you could avoid the linear search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of `particles` in the shader was incorrect, it defined a single `vec2` rather than an array of `vec2`.

The right declaration is:

```
uniform vec2 particles[100];
```